How to get robot_description from the /robot_description topic in the launch file？
i have implement that firstly start the hardware driver in the controller(Linux robot 5.15.113-rt64 #2 SMP PREEMPT_RT), the PC to open the Moveit service, and then use the Moveit programming to achieve the control of the robot in PC.
i start the hardware driver，the nodes are as fellowing:
robot@robot:~/Desktop$ ros2 node list
/body_controller
/controller_manager
/head_controller
/hyy_external_device_controller
/joint_state_broadcaster
/left_arm_controller
/right_arm_controller
/robot_state_publisher

and then i start the moveit2 services, here is the launch file：
def generate_launch_description():
    # Declare arguments
    declared_arguments = []
    declared_arguments.append( 
        DeclareLaunchArgument(
            'if_add_axisgroups', 
            default_value='true', 
            description='if true, then add axis groups'
        )
    )
    declared_arguments.append( 
        DeclareLaunchArgument(
            'if_add_external_device', 
            default_value='true', 
            description='if true, then add external devices'
        )
    )
    declared_arguments.append( 
        DeclareLaunchArgument(
            'ifstartRviz', 
            default_value='false', 
            description='if true then start Rviz'
        )
    )

    # Initialize Arguments
    if_add_axisgroups = LaunchConfiguration('if_add_axisgroups')
    if_add_external_device = LaunchConfiguration('if_add_external_device')
    ifstartRviz = LaunchConfiguration('ifstartRviz')
    
    # Get robot_description(URDF) via xacro
    robot_description_content = Command(
        [
            PathJoinSubstitution([FindExecutable(name = "xacro")]),
            " ",
            PathJoinSubstitution(
                [FindPackageShare("h1_description"), "urdf", "h1.xacro"]
            ),
            ' if_add_axisgroups:=', if_add_axisgroups,
            ' if_add_external_device:=', if_add_external_device,
        ]
    )
    robot_description = {"robot_description": robot_description_content}
    
    yaml_file_path = os.path.join(get_package_share_directory('h1_robot_moveit_config'), 'config', 'moveit_controllers.yaml')
    moveit_config = (
        MoveItConfigsBuilder("h1_robot")
        .trajectory_execution(file_path=yaml_file_path)
        .to_moveit_configs()
    )

    planning_scene_monitor_parameters = {
        "publish_planning_scene": True,
        "publish_geometry_updates": True,
        "publish_state_updates": True,
        "publish_transforms_updates": True,
    }

    # Start the actual move_group node/action server
    run_move_group_node = Node(
        package="moveit_ros_move_group",
        executable="move_group",
        output="both",
        parameters=[moveit_config.to_dict(),
                    planning_scene_monitor_parameters,
                    robot_description,
        ],
    )

    # RViz
    rviz_config_file = os.path.join(get_package_share_directory("h1_robot_moveit_config"), 'config', "moveit.rviz")
    rviz_node = Node(
        package="rviz2",
        executable="rviz2",
        name="rviz2555",
        output="both",
        arguments=["-d", rviz_config_file],
        parameters=[moveit_config.to_dict(),
                    robot_description,
        ], 
    )

    # Static TF
    static_tf = Node(
        package="tf2_ros",
        executable="static_transform_publisher",
        name="static_transform_publisher",
        output="both",
        arguments=["0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "world", "fake_link"],
        parameters=[],
    )
    
    delay_rviz_node_after_run_move_group_node = RegisterEventHandler(
        event_handler=OnProcessStart(
            target_action=run_move_group_node,  # Ensure the last controller loaded triggers this event
            on_start=[
                TimerAction(
                    period=5.0,
                    actions=[rviz_node]  # Wrap the Node in a list
                )
            ]
        ),
        condition = IfCondition(ifstartRviz)
    )

    return LaunchDescription(
        declared_arguments +
        [
            static_tf,
            run_move_group_node,
            delay_rviz_node_after_run_move_group_node
        ]
    )

and everything is working fine, then i start the task node(program with moveit api), here is the launch file:
def generate_launch_description():
    # Declare arguments
    declared_arguments = []
    declared_arguments.append( 
        DeclareLaunchArgument(
            'if_add_axisgroups', 
            default_value='true', 
            description='if true, then add axis groups'
        )
    )
    declared_arguments.append( 
        DeclareLaunchArgument(
            'if_add_external_device', 
            default_value='true', 
            description='if true, then add external devices'
        )
    )

    # Initialize Arguments
    if_add_axisgroups = LaunchConfiguration('if_add_axisgroups')
    if_add_external_device = LaunchConfiguration('if_add_external_device')
    
    # Get robot_description(URDF) via xacro
    robot_description_content = Command(
        [
            PathJoinSubstitution([FindExecutable(name = "xacro")]),
            " ",
            PathJoinSubstitution(
                [FindPackageShare("h1_description"), "urdf", "h1.xacro"]
            ),
            ' if_add_axisgroups:=', if_add_axisgroups,
            ' if_add_external_device:=', if_add_external_device,
        ]
    )
    robot_description = {"robot_description": robot_description_content}

    moveit_config = MoveItConfigsBuilder("h1_robot").to_moveit_configs()
    
    run_motion_plan_demo_node = Node(
        package="hyy_control_interface",
        executable="motion_plan_demo",
        output="screen",
        parameters=[
            moveit_config.to_dict(),
            robot_description
        ],
    )
    
    return LaunchDescription(
        declared_arguments +
        [
            run_motion_plan_demo_node
        ]
    )

there is a flaw that i have to repeat robot_description prase in each launch file, honestly,i have start robot_state_publisher node,so if i can listen to the topic /robot_description instead of xacro parse. is there any tourials and examples?

The ideal solution would be that all your nodes directly subscribe to the /robot_description topic. It doesn't make sense that you subscribe to the topic inside the other launch files and pass the string as parameter to your nodes.

You are right, but how do I subscribe /robot_description for /move_group nodes?
